# Are nested default parameters in a class' constructor possible?

Tags: c++, qt

In the beginning, the constructor for my class looked like this (simplified):

```
ProjectSerializer(MetaDataSerializerPtr metaDataSerializer);
```

Most of the time, a default MetaDataSerializer would do, so I decided to give a default to the metaDataSerializer like this:

```
ProjectSerializer(MetaDataSerializerPtr metaDataSerializer = MetaDataSerializerPtr(new MetaDataSerializer());
```

Which worked just fine, until I decided that I want the MetaDataSerializer to also have a constructor-parameter. So I tried this:

```
 ProjectSerializer(MetaDataSerializerPtr metaDataSerializer = MetaDataSerializerPtr(new MetaDataSerializer(DataManager data = DataManager())));
```

which in turn led to the following error:

> C2462 'identifier' : cannot define a type in a 'new-expression'

So, my question would be: Did I do something wrong or is it just not possible to nest default params?

Comment: The default parameter for `MetaDataSerializer`'s constructor needs to be specified at its declaration.

Comment: Are you missing a pair of parentheses after `= DataManager`?

Comment: jrok: I specified the default params for MetaDataSerializer in its own constructor and it works now, so thank you.

Comment: Borgleader: Yes, I did forget it (but only here, not in the code). Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define a type in the operand field of the **new** operator. Put the **DataManager data = DataManager** in a separate statement.

Comment: He does not seem to be trying to define type. At all.

Comment: Putting `DataManager data = DataManager` won't solve anything at all. It's not even syntactically correct and it does not make any sense on it's own even if fixed.

Comment: yeah i agree with you its syntactically wrong, i have given a generic statement that its not allowed to create any types inside operand field of new.

Comment: The compiler already did. Problem is that the explanation is kind of misleading. The compiler has a syntax error and it guesses it looks like a type definition. If it was intention of the programmer to define a type, it might help, but if it was not (like here), the programmer just ends up confused at which type definition, because there ain't any.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do exactly what you are trying because there is no way to pass a value of *data* into the ProjectSerializer constructor.  However you could do the following:

```
ProjectSerializer(MetaDataSerializerPtr metaDataSerializer = MetaDataSerializerPtr(new MetaDataSerializer(DataManager())));
```

This will allow you to default construct ProjectSerializer.

Comment: Well, that doesn't work for me. I tried it and got several C2462s all over the place for some reason.

Comment: You'll need to provide some more supporting information if that is the case.  You haven't referred to QT in your original question.  I believe the syntax of the above code is correct.  Can you construct a MetaDataSerializer on its own by passing in a DataManager?  If not, what is the signature of your MetaDataSerializer constructor?

Comment: The MetaDataSerializer's constructor is MetaDataSerializer(DataManager data). And yes, I can construct a MetaDataSerializer on its own. When I put MetaDataSerializer(DataManager data = DataManager()), I can even construct a ProjectSerializer without mentioning the DataManager in ProjectSerializers constructor. So yeah, the inital problem is solved, but why won't your solution work for me?

Comment: I would guess the errors you are seeing are based on some detail in the MetaDataSerializer or DataManager class.  I can compile the code with some skeleton classes defined.  What type of errors are you seeing when you attempt to use this method?

Comment: For example (there are 106 errors):
error C2462: 'QRasterPixmapData':cannot define a type in a 'new-expression'. Or the same error with QBlittablePixmapData, QPixmapCacheEntry and other qt-classes I don't even use anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If the `MetadataSerializer` class have the appropriate constructor, just pass an object and don't try to declare a variable like you do now:

```
ProjectSerializer(MetaDataSerializerPtr metaDataSerializer = MetaDataSerializerPtr(new MetaDataSerializer(DataManager()))
```

---

However you should be careful what you do with the pointer, as you have a possible memory leak creating the argument using `new`. You might want to look into smart pointer like [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) (or possibly [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)).

Comment: The question is tagger Qt. I suppose the Qt's parents automatically delete their children approach is being used here.

Comment: @JanHudec It all depends on what `MetaDataSerializer` and `MetaDataSerializerPtr` are and how they are used.

Comment: To clear things up: MetaDataSerializerPtr is a std::shared_ptr, so I should be quite save.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. I'm not even getting the right error anymore, but over a hundred C2462 in several qt-classes.

Comment: @bumbumfish: If `MetaDataSerializerPtr` is a `std::shared_ptr`, you should probably be using `std::make_shared` instead of cast and `new`. It is a little more efficient and syntactically safer.

Comment: @Jah Hudec: I'll have to try that, but I think I remember that std::make_shared cannot be used in constructors.

Comment: Jup, wont work, 'make_shared' is not an element of the global namespace and could therefore not be found.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to nest the expression in the default argument. Just write it as expression, not as declaration:

```
ProjectSerializer(MetaDataSerializerPtr metaDataSerializer = MetaDataSerializerPtr(new MetaDataSerializer(DataManager())));
```

It however is not possible to override that part of the default expression. Either you don't provide argument, in which case the default expression is used, or you provide argument and it is used for the *whole* argument. You can't give value for the subexpression.

You however can overload the constructor:

```
ProjectSerializer(MetaDataSerializerPtr metaDataSerializer = MetaDataSerializerPtr(new MetaDataSerializer(DataManager())));
ProjectSerializer(DataManager data) :
    ProjectSerializer(new MetaDataSerializer(data)) { /* ... */ }
```

Note, that only one of them may have default, otherwise the call without arguments would be ambiguous. But it may be either one, of course, so:

```
ProjectSerializer(MetaDataSerializerPtr metaDataSerializer);
ProjectSerializer(DataManager data = DataManager()) :
    ProjectSerializer(new MetaDataSerializer(data)) { /* ... */ }
```

is equivalent. The above shows C++11 delegating constructors. If you don't have C++11 compiler, you'll have to duplicate the initialization.

Comment: I think the first solution with a single constructor would already suffice. But it doesn't work. I get several C2462s in some qt-classes, when doing it that way.

Comment: @bumbumfish: Strange. Can you show what exactly gives you those errors? And please state your version of Visual C++.

Comment: I won't get back to my work-PC till tomorrow, but I'll look for it then.